# to reduce memory traffic

Tags: java

I am working in website application which runs on mobiles and ipods. I am using html as front end & java servlets as backend or server side processing. The servlets are embeeded with html pages. When i load a page on mobile, & make some changes it everytime servlet is called. The servlets make changes in database & shows result through html format. So it takes lot of memory. So i am asking that is there any id ea to make separation of these two processes?

Comment: That sounds like a regular (old-school) web application. Nothing wrong with that, especially for "dumb" mobiles. What exactly takes a lot of memory? And what two processes do you want to separate?

Comment: Do you mean memory or bandwidth?

Comment: Are You talking about the memory on the server or on the client?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to reduce the time you could cache the response from DB to reduce transactions (beware : lower data quality), so the page loads faster.  This does not mean necessarily a reduction in memory (infact, quite the opposite) but unless you are returning vast quantities from the DB there should be no reason why your memory usage on either the client, or the server should be massive if it's HTML for a mobile!

Answer (score 0):

Using HTTP response headers to control caching on the client side and implementing `If-Modified-Since` behaviour in your servlets can be a way to prevent doing too much work when the clients refresh their page.